# Graphql react-apollo IntrospectionFragmentMatcher issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

After adding some interface types to our graphql queries our react-apollo app was getting the fragmentMatcher error:

> You are using the simple (heuristic) fragment matcher, but your
>   queries contain union or interface types.
>        Apollo Client will not be able to able to accurately map fragments.To make this error go away, use the
>   IntrospectionFragmentMatcher as described in the docs:
>   http://dev.apollodata.com/react/initialization.html#fragment-matcher

I have followed the guide and the error does not go away, it still says I am using the heuristic fragment matcher even though I am not? Any thoughts?

Using `react-apollo@1.2.0` & `apollo-cache-inmemory@1.0.0` and here is my apollo config:

```
...

import {
  ApolloClient,
  createNetworkInterface,
  IntrospectionFragmentMatcher,
} from 'react-apollo'
import {InMemoryCache} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import SchemaData from '../data/schema.json'

const filteredData = SchemaData.data.__schema.types.filter(
  type => type.possibleTypes !== null,
)
const fragmentMatcher = new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
  introspectionQueryResultData: {
    __schema: {
      types: filteredData,
    },
  },
})
const cache = new InMemoryCache({fragmentMatcher})
...

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  networkInterface,
  dataIdFromObject: result => {
    if (result.uuid && result.__typename) {
      return result.__typename + result.uuid
    }
    return null
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to include any interface schema you may have:

```
fragmentMatcher: new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
  introspectionQueryResultData: {
    __schema: {
      types: [
        {
          kind: 'INTERFACE',
          name: 'Document',
          possibleTypes: [
            {name: 'MyInterface1'},
            {name: 'SomeInterface2'},
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
}),
```

Although I recommend using apollo v2 if possible.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451732/why-use-introspectionfragmentmatcher

Answer (score 0):

For the apollo-client 1.x, you should not use the cache that wrap the fragmentMatcher. use directly fragmentMatcher in the client constructor.