# Why use IntrospectionFragmentMatcher?

Tags: apollo

Is there any reason to use `IntrospectionFragmentMatcher` to determine concrete types of values returned from interface and union fields?

I'm talking about `apollo-client`. I'm using `InMemoryCache` with `addTypename: true`, so the type is known the moment the client gets the response.

Meanwhile my console is plagued with warnings like these: [image: console warnings]

The only reason I see the documentation hint at is response validation. But why validate the server-sent response at all? If the server is not worth trusting, validation is useless anyway.

Comment: I would like to point out that an issue is currently open for this: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4202

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warnings seem to be a bug in apollo. https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3397

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. @peping I think you are right, and I going to create a new bug as the above bug has been closed.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `useQuery` then try `fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'`.

this solved my issue.

Only a fix if you're not using cache properly

Comment: Just as a side note, it not solves actual problem. I mean, if you want to save data in cache then this is not an option.